# How to increment the dict value of multiple keys (keys are integers) which are in a range of certain numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o

I need to increment the values in my dictionary **if** their keys fall into a certain range.
My dictionary `mydict` is shown below:

```
    mydict = {2: 0, 10: 0, 23: 0, 42: 0, 89: 0, 120: 0}
    increment_range = [(1, 23), (5, 9), (45, 88)]
    for num_range in increment_range:
        mydict[keys within num_range] +=1
```

I would like an efficient solution in terms of big-oh worst case.

Comment: please show your attempts

Comment: `for num_range in increment_range:
    num_range = range(*num_range)
    mydict = {k: (v + (k in num_range))  for k,v in mydict.items()}` (Comments do not support newlines and question is already closed.)